# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake

Tags: java, openssl, ssl-certificate, java-stream, keytool

I have installed the certificate in java trust store(cacerts) using below commands:

keytool -import -file "C:\Users\kdursoji\Downloads\ZscalerRootCertificate-154478.crt" -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jre-9.0.4\lib\security\cacerts" -alias ZcalerCert

keytool -import -file "C:\Users\kdursoji\Downloads\ZscalerRootCertificate-154478.crt" -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\lib\security\cacerts" -alias ZcalerCert
    Later i am trying to hit the below url
    https://www.jllsgp.com/OMSIII/default_SSL.asp
    with apache http api and getting the below exception :

```
System property jdk.tls.client.cipherSuites is set to 'null'
    System property jdk.tls.server.cipherSuites is set to 'null'
    Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
    Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
    Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_MD5
    Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
    Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
    Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
    Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
    Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_SHA
    Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
    Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
    Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
    Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_SHA
    Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
    Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
    Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
    Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
    Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
    Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
    Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
    Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
    Inaccessible trust store: C:\Program Files\Java\jre-9.0.4\lib\security\jssecacerts
    trustStore is: C:\Program Files\Java\jre-9.0.4\lib\security\cacerts
    trustStore type is: pkcs12
    trustStore provider is: 
    the last modified time is: Thu Aug 01 21:03:36 IST 2019
    Reload the trust store
    Reload trust certs
    Reloaded 105 trust certs
    adding as trusted cert:
      Subject: CN=Equifax Secure Global eBusiness CA-1, O=Equifax Secure Inc., C=US
      Issuer:  CN=Equifax Secure Global eBusiness CA-1, O=Equifax Secure Inc., C=US
      Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0xc3517
      Valid from Mon Jun 21 09:30:00 IST 1999 until Mon Jun 22 09:30:00 IST 2020

    adding as trusted cert:
      Subject: CN=Entrust Root Certification Authority - EC1, OU="(c) 2012 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only", OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms, O="Entrust, Inc.", C=US
      Issuer:  CN=Entrust Root Certification Authority - EC1, OU="(c) 2012 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only", OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms, O="Entrust, Inc.", C=US
      Algorithm: EC; Serial number: 0xa68b79290000000050d091f9
      Valid from Tue Dec 18 20:55:36 IST 2012 until Fri Dec 18 21:25:36 IST 2037

    adding as trusted cert:
      Subject: CN=SecureTrust CA, O=SecureTrust Corporation, C=US
      Issuer:  CN=SecureTrust CA, O=SecureTrust Corporation, C=US
      Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0xcf08e5c0816a5ad427ff0eb271859d0
      Valid from Wed Nov 08 01:01:18 IST 2006 until Tue Jan 01 01:10:55 IST 2030

    adding as trusted cert:
      Subject: OU=Security Communication RootCA1, O=SECOM Trust.net, C=JP
      Issuer:  OU=Security Communication RootCA1, O=SECOM Trust.net, C=JP
      Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x0
      Valid from Tue Sep 30 09:50:49 IST 2003 until Sat Sep 30 09:50:49 IST 2023

    adding as trusted cert:
      Subject: CN=DigiCert Global Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
      Issuer:  CN=DigiCert Global Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
      Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x83be056904246b1a1756ac95991c74a
      Valid from Fri Nov 10 05:30:00 IST 2006 until Mon Nov 10 05:30:00 IST 2031

    adding as trusted cert:
      Subject: CN=QuoVadis Root CA 2 G3, O=QuoVadis Limited, C=BM
      Issuer:  CN=QuoVadis Root CA 2 G3, O=QuoVadis Limited, C=BM
      Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x445734245b81899b35f2ceb82b3b5ba726f07528
      Valid from Fri Jan 13 00:29:32 IST 2012 until Mon Jan 13 00:29:32 IST 2042

    adding as trusted cert:
      Subject: CN=DigiCert Trusted Root G4, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
      Issuer:  CN=DigiCert Trusted Root G4, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
      Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x59b1b579e8e2132e23907bda777755c
      Valid from Thu Aug 01 17:30:00 IST 2013 until Fri Jan 15 17:30:00 IST 2038

    adding as trusted cert:
      Subject: CN=GeoTrust Primary Certification Authority, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
      Issuer:  CN=GeoTrust Primary Certification Authority, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
      Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x18acb56afd69b6153a636cafdafac4a1
      Valid from Mon Nov 27 05:30:00 IST 2006 until Thu Jul 17 05:29:59 IST 2036
    adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: EMAILADDRESS=support@zscaler.com, CN=Zscaler Root CA, OU=Zscaler Inc., O=Zscaler Inc., L=San Jose, ST=California, C=US
  Issuer:  EMAILADDRESS=support@zscaler.com, CN=Zscaler Root CA, OU=Zscaler Inc., O=Zscaler Inc., L=San Jose, ST=California, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0xdbbe982d89b77b93
  Valid from Fri Dec 19 05:57:55 IST 2014 until Tue May 06 05:57:55 IST 2042
   adding as trusted cert:
      Subject: EMAILADDRESS=support@zscaler.com, CN=Zscaler Root CA, OU=Zscaler Inc., O=Zscaler Inc., L=San Jose, ST=California, C=US
      Issuer:  EMAILADDRESS=support@zscaler.com, CN=Zscaler Root CA, OU=Zscaler Inc., O=Zscaler Inc., L=San Jose, ST=California, C=US
      Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0xdbbe982d89b77b93
      Valid from Fri Dec 19 05:57:55 IST 2014 until Tue May 06 05:57:55 IST 2042

    adding as trusted cert:
      Subject: CN=DigiCert Global Root G3, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
      Issuer:  CN=DigiCert Global Root G3, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
      Algorithm: EC; Serial number: 0x55556bcf25ea43535c3a40fd5ab4572
      Valid from Thu Aug 01 17:30:00 IST 2013 until Fri Jan 15 17:30:00 IST 2038

    adding as trusted cert:
      Subject: CN=UTN-USERFirst-Client Authentication and Email, OU=http://www.usertrust.com, O=The USERTRUST Network, L=Salt Lake City, ST=UT, C=US
      Issuer:  CN=UTN-USERFirst-Client Authentication and Email, OU=http://www.usertrust.com, O=The USERTRUST Network, L=Salt Lake City, ST=UT, C=US
      Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x44be0c8b500024b411d336252567c989
      Valid from Fri Jul 09 22:58:50 IST 1999 until Tue Jul 09 23:06:58 IST 2019

    adding as trusted cert:
      Subject: CN=Class 2 Primary CA, O=Certplus, C=FR
      Issuer:  CN=Class 2 Primary CA, O=Certplus, C=FR
      Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x85bd4bf3d8dae369f694d75fc3a54423
      Valid from Wed Jul 07 22:35:00 IST 1999 until Sun Jul 07 05:29:59 IST 2019

    adding as trusted cert:
      Subject: CN=GeoTrust Global CA, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
      Issuer:  CN=GeoTrust Global CA, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
      Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x23456
      Valid from Tue May 21 09:30:00 IST 2002 until Sat May 21 09:30:00 IST 2022

    adding as trusted cert:
      Subject: CN=SwissSign Platinum CA - G2, O=SwissSign AG, C=CH
      Issuer:  CN=SwissSign Platinum CA - G2, O=SwissSign AG, C=CH
      Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x4eb200670c035d4f
      Valid from Wed Oct 25 14:06:00 IST 2006 until Sat Oct 25 14:06:00 IST 2036

 adding as trusted cert:
      Subject: CN=GlobalSign, O=GlobalSign, OU=GlobalSign ECC Root CA - R5
      Issuer:  CN=GlobalSign, O=GlobalSign, OU=GlobalSign ECC Root CA - R5
      Algorithm: EC; Serial number: 0x605949e0262ebb55f90a778a71f94ad86c
      Valid from Tue Nov 13 05:30:00 IST 2012 until Tue Jan 19 08:44:07 IST 2038 

   keyStore is : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\lib\security\cacerts
    keyStore type is : pkcs12
    keyStore provider is : 
    init keystore
    init keymanager of type SunX509
    trigger seeding of SecureRandom
    done seeding SecureRandom
    Errorjava.security.KeyManagementException: Default SSLContext is initialized automatically
    Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
    Allow legacy hello messages: true
    Is initial handshake: true
    Is secure renegotiation: false
    main, setSoTimeout(0) called
    main, the previous server name in SNI (type=host_name (0), value=www.jllsgp.com) was replaced with (type=host_name (0), value=www.jllsgp.com)
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
    %% No cached client session
    update handshake state: client_hello[1]
    upcoming handshake states: server_hello[2]
    *** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
    RandomCookie:  random_bytes = {6F 62 1B 73 37 B7 F1 93 CB 43 36 98 6A CC A9 27 5D 22 F2 AC 06 A0 2E C9 5D 29 20 77 5D 34 64 24}
    Session ID:  {}
    Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
    Compression Methods:  { 0 }
    Extension supported_groups, group names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp256k1, ffdhe2048, ffdhe3072, ffdhe4096, ffdhe6144, ffdhe8192}
    Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
    Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
    Extension extended_master_secret
    Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=www.jllsgp.com]
    Extension status_request_v2
    CertStatusReqItemV2: ocsp_multi, OCSPStatusRequest
        ResponderIds: <EMPTY>
        Extensions: <EMPTY>
    CertStatusReqItemV2: ocsp, OCSPStatusRequest
        ResponderIds: <EMPTY>
        Extensions: <EMPTY>
    Extension status_request: ocsp, OCSPStatusRequest
        ResponderIds: <EMPTY>
        Extensions: <EMPTY>
    ***
    main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 269
    [Raw write]: length = 274
    0000: 16 03 03 01 0D 01 00 01   09 03 03 6F 62 1B 73 37  ...........ob.s7
    0010: B7 F1 93 CB 43 36 98 6A   CC A9 27 5D 22 F2 AC 06  ....C6.j..']"...
    0020: A0 2E C9 5D 29 20 77 5D   34 64 24 00 00 64 C0 2C  ...]) w]4d$..d.,
    0030: C0 2B C0 30 00 9D C0 2E   C0 32 00 9F 00 A3 C0 2F  .+.0.....2...../
    0040: 00 9C C0 2D C0 31 00 9E   00 A2 C0 24 C0 28 00 3D  ...-.1.....$.(.=
    0050: C0 26 C0 2A 00 6B 00 6A   C0 0A C0 14 00 35 C0 05  .&.*.k.j.....5..
    0060: C0 0F 00 39 00 38 C0 23   C0 27 00 3C C0 25 C0 29  ...9.8.#.'.<.%.)
    0070: 00 67 00 40 C0 09 C0 13   00 2F C0 04 C0 0E 00 33  .g.@...../.....3
    0080: 00 32 C0 08 C0 12 00 0A   C0 03 C0 0D 00 16 00 13  .2..............
    0090: 00 FF 01 00 00 7C 00 0A   00 20 00 1E 00 17 00 18  ......... ......
    00A0: 00 19 00 09 00 0A 00 0B   00 0C 00 0D 00 0E 00 16  ................
    00B0: 01 00 01 01 01 02 01 03   01 04 00 0B 00 02 01 00  ................
    00C0: 00 0D 00 16 00 14 06 03   06 01 05 03 05 01 04 03  ................
    00D0: 04 01 04 02 02 03 02 01   02 02 00 17 00 00 00 00  ................
    00E0: 00 13 00 11 00 00 0E 77   77 77 2E 6A 6C 6C 73 67  .......www.jllsg
    00F0: 70 2E 63 6F 6D 00 11 00   10 00 0E 02 00 04 00 00  p.com...........
    0100: 00 00 01 00 04 00 00 00   00 00 05 00 05 01 00 00  ................
    0110: 00 00                                              ..
    main, received EOFException: error
    main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
    main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
    main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
    [Raw write]: length = 7
    0000: 15 03 03 00 02 02 28                               ......(
    main, called closeSocket()
    Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
        at com.cscinfo.nemo.http.TestHttps.main(TestHttps.java:57)
    Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(Unknown Source)
        ... 12 more
```

And used code is :

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.net.URLConnection;

    import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
    import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
    import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
    import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
    import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
    import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

    import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts;

    public class TestHttps {
        public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

            // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
            TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
                public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }

                public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }
            } };
            // Install the all-trusting trust manager
            try {
                SSLContext sc = SSLContexts.createSystemDefault();

                sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
                HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error" + e);
            }
            // Now you can access an https URL without having the certificate in the
            // truststore
            try {
                HostnameVerifier hv = new HostnameVerifier() {
                    public boolean verify(String urlHostName, SSLSession session) {
                        System.out.println("Warning: URL Host: " + urlHostName + " vs. " + session.getPeerHost());
                        return true;
                    }
                };

                URL url = new URL("https://www.jllsgp.com/OMSIII/default_SSL.asp");
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                HttpsURLConnection urlConn = (HttpsURLConnection) conn;
                urlConn.setHostnameVerifier(hv);
                // conn.setDoOutput(true);
                System.out.println(urlConn.getResponseCode());

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                System.out.println("Error in SLL Connetion" + e);
            }

        }
    }

I am expecting a 200 response code while hitting.But getting the above exception.So could you please any body can help me in this one ?*
```

Comment: (1) changing files in `Program Files [(x86)]` on 'recent' Windows (since Vista or Seven, I don't recall) often dosn't work (2) that server uses a Digicert cert that validates fine with the default truststore in (Oracle) Java 9.0.4 (3) your trust-all config accepts any cert (and every fake server) anyway (4) 'zscaler' suggests you might be going through an enterprise proxy/IDS/IPS/interceptor/etc -- are you? If so your problem is likely with that not the actual server (5) run with sysprop `javax.net.debug=ssl,handshake` and look at the output; add to your Q if needed.

Comment: Thanks for reply dave..now i have provided the debug messages in question and let me know if you get any thing.

Comment: Your system is receiving 'EOF' (= TCP FIN) after sending ClientHello. My tests with OpenSSL show that server supports 1.2 and one of those ciphersuites and SNI, and decent servers don't FIN for extensions, so my guess now focusses on (4): you aren't connecting to the real server, but some kind of interceptor, which is either rejecting (nonstandardly) or failing for some unknown reason. Are you resolving to IPaddr 203.76.172.134 like me? (Even if you do, 'transparent' interception uses the real IPaddr.) Did/can you try connecting using different ISPs?

Comment: Yup Dave.Your correct .Zscaler  ISP service preventing the request.Just i will ask admin team to bypass the incoming request from Zscaler.

Comment: Thank you Dave for helping me in finding the root cause .

Answer (score 0):

In my case, navigator was abble to access the URL (because of a proxy) but java not...

To test if you are in the same case, just ping your domain in a console. If ping times out, you have to dig in that direction ;)